# GcpDatastoreEmulatorAutoConfiguration doesn't happen before GcpDatastoreAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to set a spring boot application, using `Datastore` as DB storage.

For that I use the spring-cloud-gcp starter dependency to auto-configure the `Datastore` instance for me.

Since I want to work with two spring profiles - one production and one dev/integration-tests profile, I am trying to set the dev profile to utilize the `LocalDatastoreHelper` (auto-configured in `GcpDatastoreEmulatorAutoConfiguration`), hence my `application-dev.properties` defines the following (as documented [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/datastore.html#_cloud_datastore_settings))

```
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator.store-on-disk=true
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator.port=8081
```

During the booting of the DEV application, I have several beans that depend on the Datastore to query/insert DEV data to it.

The problem comes from the fact that when `GcpDatastoreAutoConfiguration` detects the presence of emulator settings, it automatically directs traffic to the emulator, which is not started until the Application is running, causing an `I/O` error.

I looked up the source code of `GcpDatastoreEmulatorAutoConfiguration` and it seems like it's supposed to run before the `GcpDatastoreAutoConfiguration` ([doc](https://googleapis.dev/java/spring-cloud-gcp/latest/com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/datastore/GcpDatastoreEmulatorAutoConfiguration.html)):

```
@AutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator.enabled")
@AutoConfigureBefore(GcpDatastoreAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(GcpDatastoreProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(LocalDatastoreHelper.class)
public class GcpDatastoreEmulatorAutoConfiguration implements SmartLifecycle{
    
    //config code... 
}
```

My guess is that `SmartLifecycle` overrides the expected behavior, as the configuration is not started until the `DEFAULT_PHASE` which is `Integer.MAX_INT`. I am fairly unfamiliar with `SmartLifecycle`, but according to the javadoc, seems like it will pospone its initialization for the last phase of the Spring Context initialization.

Has anyone got an idea how to fix this? How can I make the Emulator run prior to the initialization of the `Datastore` bean?